# Is there a way to add the '%' symbol to my pivoted result in Oracle SQL and convert them to to_char

Tags: sql, oracle, format, append, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a table with multiple columns but i also want to append a '%' symbol for 1 row. Also i need the row to display 1 decimal point.

Original query:

```
select distinct a.TIME_DESC,
round(sum(a.TRX_VOLUMES)) TRx_volume,
round(sum(TARGET_TRX_VOLUMES)) Goal,
round(sum(a.TRX_VOLUMES_LY)) TRx_volume_LY,
round((sum(a.TRX_VOLUMES)/sum(c.TRX_VOLUMES_MKT))*100,1) Mkt_share
from a
join b on a.BRAND_ID=b.BRAND_ID and a.GEO_ID=b.GEO_ID
and a.TIMEPERIODTYPE=b.TIMEPERIODTYPE and a.TIME_DESC=b.TIME_DESC
join c on a.BRAND_ID=c.BRAND_ID and a.GEO_ID=c.GEO_ID
and a.TIMEPERIODTYPE=c.TIMEPERIODTYPE and a.TIME_DESC=c.TIME_DESC
where a.GEO_DESC='BC/YK' and a.type_code='B' and a.dash_brand='Copaxone'
and a.TIMEPERIODTYPE='YEAR'
group by a.TIME_DESC
```

For the row i am pivoting i have used

```
with stg1 as (select distinct a.TIME_DESC,
round(sum(a.TRX_VOLUMES)) TRx_volume,
round(sum(TARGET_TRX_VOLUMES)) Goal,
round(sum(a.TRX_VOLUMES_LY)) TRx_volume_LY,
round((sum(a.TRX_VOLUMES)/sum(c.TRX_VOLUMES_MKT))*100,1) Mkt_share
from a
join b on a.BRAND_ID=b.BRAND_ID and a.GEO_ID=b.GEO_ID
and a.TIMEPERIODTYPE=b.TIMEPERIODTYPE and a.TIME_DESC=b.TIME_DESC
join c on a.BRAND_ID=c.BRAND_ID and a.GEO_ID=c.GEO_ID
and a.TIMEPERIODTYPE=c.TIMEPERIODTYPE and a.TIME_DESC=c.TIME_DESC
where a.GEO_DESC='BC/YK' and a.type_code='B' and a.dash_brand='Copaxone'
and a.TIMEPERIODTYPE='YEAR'
group by a.TIME_DESC),
stg5 AS (SELECT * FROM (select time_desc, Mkt_share from stg1)
pivot
(SUM(Mkt_share) FOR time_desc IN ('Jan 2020', 'Feb 2020', 'Mar 2020', 'Apr 2020', 'May 2020', 'Jun 2020', 'Jul 2020', 'Aug 2020', 'Sep 2020', 'Oct 2020', 'Nov 2020', 'Dec 2020')))
select 'MS %', d.* from stg5 d


'MS%'   'Jan 2020'  'Feb 2020'  'Mar 2020'  
MS %    7           6.5           7.1
```

I want to add a demimal for the 7 to make it a 7.0 along with a % symbol. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a way, but doesn't look pretty and is far from any "dynamic" kind of thing.

This is an ordinary pivot query:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from
  3    (select deptno, sal
  4     from emp
  5    )
  6  pivot
  7  (sum(sal) sumsal
  8   for deptno in (10, 20, 30)
  9  )
 10  order by 1;

 10_SUMSAL  20_SUMSAL  30_SUMSAL
---------- ---------- ----------
     13750      10995       9400

SQL>
```

Suppose you want to format those salaries; then you'd do something like this:

```
SQL> select to_char("10_SUMSAL", '99990D0') || '%' as "10",
  2         to_char("20_SUMSAL", '99990D0') || '%' as "20",
  3         to_char("30_SUMSAL", '99990D0') || '%' as "30"
  4  from
  5    (select deptno, sal
  6     from emp
  7    )
  8  pivot
  9  (sum(sal) sumsal
 10   for deptno in (10, 20, 30, 40)
 11  )
 12  order by 1;

10        20        30
--------- --------- ---------
 13750,0%  10995,0%   9400,0%

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is reformatting pivoted columns such like

`TO_CHAR( "Jan 2020",'fm999G990D0','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')||'%'`

but do more, convert your query to a dynamic one by creating such a function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_brands_volume RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  sqlqry    VARCHAR2(32767);
  cols1     VARCHAR2(32767);
  cols2     VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(''''||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level,'mm'),'Mon yyyy')||''' AS "'||
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level,'mm'),'Mon yyyy')||'"' ,',') 
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level)
    INTO cols1
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 12; 

  SELECT LISTAGG('TO_CHAR( "'||TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level,'mm'),'Mon yyyy')||'",''fm999G990D0'',
                             ''NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''''.,'''''') AS "'||
                               TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(level,'mm'),'Mon yyyy')||'"',',') 
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY level)
    INTO cols2   
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 12;
 
  sqlqry :=
  'WITH stg1  AS
   (SELECT DISTINCT a.TIME_DESC,
                    ROUND(SUM(a.TRX_VOLUMES)) TRx_volume,
                    ROUND(SUM(TARGET_TRX_VOLUMES)) Goal,
                    ROUND(SUM(a.TRX_VOLUMES_LY)) TRx_volume_LY,
                    ROUND((SUM(a.TRX_VOLUMES) / SUM(c.TRX_VOLUMES_MKT)) * 100,1) Mkt_share
      FROM a
      JOIN b
        ON a.BRAND_ID = b.BRAND_ID
       AND a.GEO_ID = b.GEO_ID
       AND a.TIMEPERIODTYPE = b.TIMEPERIODTYPE
       AND a.TIME_DESC = b.TIME_DESC
      JOIN c
        ON a.BRAND_ID = c.BRAND_ID
       AND a.GEO_ID = c.GEO_ID
       AND a.TIMEPERIODTYPE = c.TIMEPERIODTYPE
       AND a.TIME_DESC = c.TIME_DESC
     where a.GEO_DESC = ''BC/YK''
       AND a.type_code = ''B''
       AND a.d ASh_brAND = ''Copaxone''
       AND a.TIMEPERIODTYPE = ''YEAR''
     GROUP BY a.TIME_DESC),
  stg5  AS
   (SELECT '||cols2||'
      FROM stg1
      PIVOT(
             MAX(Mkt_share) FOR time_desc IN('||cols1||')
            )
   )';    

  OPEN recordset FOR sqlqry;
  RETURN recordset;
END;
```

for the months of the current year, and then call from SQL Developer's command line

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := get_brands_volume;
PRINT rc
```